# Remotely build iOS app

Tags: ios, macos, ssh, cmd, remoting

I'm building an iPhone app on windows, but have a macbook air that I keep around so that I can build my .ipk when I need to.

My question is: how (if it's possible) do I make my macbook build remotely (either by calling a command through ssh or similar), all the files are being synced already by dropbox, so i'm not concerned about how to get the files back and forth, just how to make my mac build remotely.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: for sure it is possible since Phonegap has this option to build at they server. I am not sure if I ever will use that option. "Never say never"

Comment: Yeah, it's obviously not the option that everyone would want/need, but I'm sick of having to switch computers just to do a build, haha.

Comment: how do you test your app with this setup? No access to virtual device over ssh..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your project using xcodebuild. Log through ssh, go to project catalog and just run xcodebuild. You may add some parameters if required.

Comment: I've marked your question as correct, but as a follow up: are you aware of what parameters would be required for an ios build? or will it just grab all the details from the xcode project file?

Comment: It depends on, what do you need ;) Try 'xcodebuild -list' to get basic options, and man xcodebuild for more info. I don't have much experience with this; for my needs 'xcodebuild -configuration Debug' was enough. (but yes, basically it should work on its own)